# When an ssh session is forcibly disconnected, readline breaks (mac)

Tags: ssh, terminal, readline

On Mac's iTerm app, when I ssh into remote machines and the connection is terminated by either power loss or connection failure, some of the time, readline in the terminal fails.  At least, I think it's readline - the main symptom is that history-search-backward and history-search-forward no longer function.  The part I can't understand is that it is broken on *both* the local and remote machines even after establishing a new connection.  The other strange part is that the failure only happens some of the time, not every time I get disconnected.

I think this could be a problem with ssh, mac's terminal, or just the iTerm app, but I have no idea where to start looking.  Any ideas would be appreciated, but with such a convoluted problem I can't really expect any solutions.

Comment: This is not a programming related question. Superuser or askdifferent would be a better option.

Comment: Not sure what you're experiencing, but I suspect your terminal settings are getting thrown off by the way your ssh gets killed.  Try typing "reset" in your terminal as a possible fix.

Comment: Thanks, reset fixed it - is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @Ikke: I flagged this post to be moved to superuser

Comment: @bigendian - That's the solution.  Is it documented anywhere?  I'll accept it as an answer if you post it.  I'm still curious why in case anyone else has a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal settings are being through off by something, and the reset command can be used to fix them.

I'm actually not sure why this happens, but I suspect that some binary may be getting passed to the shell which is interpreting it as control codes that change how your shell operates.